# how to stop cron job runing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, cronjobs

> in my site runing cron job (but it take RAM and CPU Usage )
>
> So i want to stop cron job

**how to stop cron job runing in magento 2**

Comment: You can run remove cron command:   

**`php bin/magento cron:remove`**  

And all cron will be remove

Comment: it will delete the codes ......

Comment: can i just  stop

Comment: It will just remove all the cron

Comment: what happen i run php bin/magento cron:remove  this comment

Comment: no it will not delete codes

Comment: only the scheduled cron jobs but not the exact code

Comment: agin if i want to run     cron job 
what i do

Comment: just run using command cron:run twice

Comment: hm ok thank you i will check

Answer (score 8):

You can by running cron remove command:
**`php bin/magento cron:remove`**

It will only remove cron tasks from crontab but not the exact cron codes/files.

If you wish to run the cron jobs again, you just need to run cron run command twice:
**`php bin/magento cron:run`**

> The first time run is to discover cron tasks to run and the second time — to run the tasks themselves.
>   The **second cron** **run** must occur on or after the **`scheduled_at time`** for every task.

Comment: after runing cron:remove  can i re:index  to complete the process

Comment: not necessary ..but you can

Comment: i have one doubt bro

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in magento root CLI

```
php bin/magento cron:remove
```

> NOTE : This command has no effect on cron jobs outside the #~ MAGENTO START and #~ MAGENTO END comments in your crontab.

and to do it manually

Go -> CLI

then enter **crontab -e**

an editor will open and go command out the crons which you want to disable.

For more information about creating, running and stop cron [visit here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Hope it helps.